# Iterate through an array randomly but fast

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, random

I have a 2d array that I need to iterate through randomly. This is part of an update loop in a little simulation, so it runs about 200 times a second. Currently I am achieving this by creating a array of the appropriate size, filling it with a range, and shuffling it to use to subscript my other arrays.

```
std::array<int, 250> nums;
std::iota(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0);

timer += fElapsedTime;
if (timer >= 0.005f)
{
    std::shuffle(nums.begin(), nums.end(), engine);

    for (int xi : nums)
    {
        std::shuffle(nums.begin(), nums.end(), engine);

        for (int yi : nums)
        {
            // use xi and yi as array subscript and do stuff
        }
    }

    timer = 0.0f;
}
```

The issue with this solution is that is is really *slow*. Just removing the std::shuffles increases the fps by almost 2.5x, so the entire program logic is almost insignificant compared to just these shuffles.

Is there some type of code that would allow me to generate a fixed range (0 - 249) of non-repeating randomly generated ints that I could either use directly or write to an array and then iterate over?

Comment: *so it runs about 200 times a second* -- Are you timing a release build or a debug, unoptimized build?  200 times a second for something this simple sounds odd to me.

Comment: You are shuffling a range you are iterating over. There is just about no case where this is correct. It is almost certain that you won't visit each value in `for (int xi : nums)` and that you will visit some of them multiple times. It looks like the intention is for the inner shuffle to randomize the `y` order, but it is also shuffling the `x` order. It seems to me like you should have an array of indices or iteratiors which you could shuffle for each `xi`. This won't fix your speed issue, but it will fix an error you haven't noticed yet.

Comment: Use a profiler to find out which part of your code is slow. Maybe `engine` is too slow for your application. Maybe try a [`std::linear_congruential_engine`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/linear_congruential_engine) like `std::minstd_rand` which should be very fast but not as random as other engines.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I hadn't noticed this. My simulation was producing almost good results but something was off about it. This is definitely it thank you.

Comment: Are your array sizes  fixed at 250x250? Is the goal to randomly access all elements of an array without accessing a position twice?

Comment: @doug That is exactly the case. The quality of the randomness is not super important.

Comment: Do you have to randomize the entire array access pattern each time round the loop, or could you get away with randomizing a few elements of the access pattern each time round the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should shuffle the entire matrix rather than going through one row/column at a time. This should work pretty fast. It's 125k and should be reasonably cache friendly.

```
constexpr int N = 250;
std::array<uint16_t, N* N> nums;
std::iota(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0);
std::shuffle(nums.begin(), nums.end(), engine);

for (auto x : nums)
{
    auto xi = x / N;
    auto yi = x % N;
    // Do Stuff indexed on x and y
}
```

Comment: I have implemented and tested this to give a reasonable improvement in performance while maintaining the desired effect, so unless something even better comes along I will accept this as the answer.